# speed limit of syn scanning ports of multiple targets?

Tags: python, linux, performance

I've coded a small raw packet syn port scanner to scan a list of ips and find out if they're online. (btw. for Debian in python2.7)

The basic intention was to simply check if some websites are reachable and speed up that process by preceding a raw syn request (port 80) but I stumbled upon something.

Just for fun I started trying to find out how fast I could get with this (fastest as far as i know) check technique and it turns out that despite I'm only sending raw syn packets on one port and listening for responses on that same port (with tcpdump) the connection reliability quite drops starting at about 1500-2000 packets/sec and shortly thereafter almost the entire networking starts blocking on the box.

I thought about it and if I compare this value with e.g. torrent seeding/leeching packets/sec the scan speed is quiet slow.

I have a few ideas why this happens but I'm not a professional and I have no clue how to check if I'm right with my assumptions.

Firstly it could be that the Linux networking has some fancy internal port forwarding stuff running to keep the sending port opened (maybe some sort of feature of iptables?) because the script seems to be able to receive syn-ack even with closed sourceport.

If so, is it possible to prevent or bypass that in some fashion?

Another guess is that the python library is simply too dumb to do real proper raw packet management but that's unlikely because its using internal Linux functions to do that as far as I know.

- Does anyone have a clue why that network blocking is happening?
- Where's the difference to torrent connections or anything else like that?
- Do I have to send the packets in another way or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months ago I found out that this problem is well known as c10k problem.
It has to do amongst other things with how the kernel allocates and processes tcp connections internally.
The only efficient way to address the issue is to bypass the kernel tcp stack and implement various other low-level things by your own.
All good approaches I know are working with low-level async implementations
There are some good ways to deal with the problem depending on the scale.
For further information i would recommend to search for the c10k problem.